# Why am I getting an error when I try to get the height of an element from a rel tag?

Tags: jquery, rel

I'm trying to build the functionality of revealing more of an element when you click on a link that has a rel tag that references it.

```
    <div class="reveal-more"><a href="#" rel="#new-deals">View More Deals &#9660;</a></div>

$(".reveal-more a").click( function() {
    var moreContainer = $(this).attr('rel');
    var moreContainerHeight = $("'" + moreContainer + "'").height;
    alert(moreContainerHeight);

    return false;
});
```

Chrome keeps throwing the error - Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#new-deals'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be having issues with the wrapping of the variable, try changing the code to the following, I found that it works O.K. with the code as this:

```
<div class="reveal-more"><a href="#" rel="#new-deals">View More Deals &#9660;</a></div>

    $(".reveal-more a").click( function() {
        var moreContainer = $(this).attr('rel');
        var moreContainerHeight = $(moreContainer).height();
        alert(moreContainerHeight);

        return false;
    });
```

I believe your problem was that you had a string object and you were wrapping the string in `''` when jQuery automatically handles this.

**EDIT:** Amended code

Comment: Yeah, I tried that also it runs but doesn't output a height it alerts line 4 of JQuery. i.e. - function(i,o){... and so on for several lines.

Comment: Sorry, the `.height()` is a function, not a variable. So you must change `.height` to be `.height()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're asking for a height of a class.

Really you need to ask for the height of an ID.

A class could relate to a series of divs, all with different heights.

Comment: #new-deals is a reference to an id, not a class that would be .new-deals

Comment: I see, my mistake. But the #new-deals relates to the <a> tag, not the div, and it's the div you want to expand isn't it?

Comment: So wouldn't it be     var moreContainerHeight = $("'" + moreContainer + "'").parent().height;

Comment: No, a rel tag is a way to set a reference to another object in the DOM. Right now the way I have it the program should be reading it as $("#new-deals").height which is exactly the element I want to pull the height from.

Comment: jQuery seems to have been wrapping it again after you did so it was invalid javascript, hence the error, see my answer for the solution I found.